# Name for style of text logo where two colours overlap imperfectly?

Tags: logo, style-identification

I've seen a bunch of these - often with similar colour palettes of red with blue/green/turquoise. There are two overlapping copies of the design in two solid colours, which are almost (but not quite) exactly the same and overlap in a way which is almost (but not quite) consistent.

Does it have a name?

This is the logo of madeByRaygun:

[image]

Comment: I think both answers are correct. It's basically mis-registered stereoscopic 3d.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd call that "Fake 3D" (or Fake "stereoscopic 3D", as suggested in comments) style. People started copying the 2D look of this 3D faking technique probably without realizing what it originally is used for. The red/green channels left and right of the original black logo shape mimic a technique used to make things appear 3D when viewed through glasses with one red and one green toned side.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Moonstereo1897.jpg from the sterepscopy article on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereoscopy

*[Edit to reflect some of the comments and other answers:]*

As @Brendan and other users suggested, the case could equally likely be an "offset printing job where two spot colors don't quite line up".

The logo uses a **deliberate "misregistration"**, mimicing either a techniqual glitch or a 3D technique. Regardless of which of the possible two variations is in question here, this approach *stylizes* a technical feature and makes deliberate reference to a glitch or sorts.

Comment: Ah! of course! couldn't figure out why it was so familiar / colours so consistent! tx

Comment: +1, but "Fake 3D" could mean a lot of different methods of faking a 3D effect (hearing "fake 3D" I'd assume the speaker meant bevel effects). I'd call it *"stereoscopic 3D"* if you were feeling fancy or talking to someone knowledgable, or *"retro 3D glasses style"* or *"like images for old-style 3D glasses"* if you just want to get the point across :)

Comment: It's bad fake 3d, though, as for stereoscopic 3d to work, the x-axis has to be aligned (only the y axis should be shifted).

Comment: @DA01 makes a good point. I do not think this is anything to do with 3d though.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. I don't feel the sample logo is in any way trying to emulate a stereoscopic image. It seems to me more like it's trying to look like a misaligned print head image.

Comment: @keavon we would need more samples really. Also this might be a stylistic misregistration / overlap of colors inspired by the recent popularity of stereoscopic images, while not trying to be that in itself

Answer (score 6):

To me, it looks like an offset printing job where two spot colors don't quite line up. "Misregistration" is probably the term to use for that effect.

Comment: Certainly a possibility also. Having seen this "style" appear more and more often recently when at the same time 3D has become a big thing in the digital content industry, I do think, however, it has its roots in a misconception there.

Answer (score 6):

Since no one mentioned it yet , a visual artifact like that you showed in the picture can be also called a 3D Anaglyph http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_3D.

This is mostly obtained by getting a stereoscopic photo by the use of two cameras and overlapping them so the addition of some channels is not exactly aligned (usually Red and Blue).

You can fake this effect in Photoshop easily by playing around with the channels in the channels, on a RGB picture, try selecting just the red channel and move it, then move just the blue channel in the opposite direction and experiment with the effect

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned here, and on LogoLounge.com's [2012 Logo Design Trends](http://www.logolounge.com/article.asp) report, it's called Anaglyph.

LogoLounge's Bill Gardner had this to say about the use of the Anaglyph trend in logo design:

> Messaging from these marks creates a dichotomy of choice. They are
>   obvious enough that certainly no special glasses are required to grasp
>   the intent. This technique tells the viewer they may make the choice
>   of this or that but not both. But they also convey that the viewer is
>   responsible for her own selection. Because this is a novel and
>   interactive technique, it commands a response which ensures a few
>   additional milliseconds of attention while the consumer deciphers her
>   options.