# how do you do text effect like this CMYK offset-effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, text, effects

[image]

How do you do this in Photoshop?
I am using Photoshop cc and Illustrator and I am in the process of learning. Can anyone teach me how to do that text effect shown in the picture? thanks!

Comment: For something like this we ask you show that you've made some attempt to try on your own and got stuck at some point along the way.

Comment: This is called [misregistration](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/13134/8708), I would suggest using that as a search term

Comment: Take your type layer, duplicate it 3 times, change the hue of each with a colorize tool. (nitpicky trivia: this would likely never happen in real life as you wouldn't use cyan, magenta and yellow overprinting to create Black. You'd just use black ink.)

Comment: Tricks like this are based on overlapping shapes with [blend modes](http://www.northlite.net/designorati/illustrator/blendmodes/blendmodes.htm)

Comment: Copy Paste Copy Paste Copy Paste Layer Colour Layer Colour Layer Colour ... oh and don't forget the transparency!

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in Illustrator by simply stacking fills and adjusting them via the **Appearance Panel**.

[image: misreg]

The `Transform` effect for each fill, simply moves the fill vertically so they are off-center.

Comment: great answer... but no black in OP... it was generated from the overlap as shown in @George Profenza's post below.

Comment: Answer was more about theory than actual creation. But, okay, you're right. Image updated.

Comment: and now the +1 :-)

Answer (score 4):

That's an example of the subtractive color synthesis.
In illustrator you can do that by using a subtractive blend mode like multiply in the transparency panel:
[image: subtractive colours illustrator]

To prove the concept I'm using 3 text elements filled with cyan, magenta and yellow.
When all the layers overlap, they subtract from each other resulting in black