# What is the name for the "broken line" effect seen here?

Tags: typography, effects

And how does one do this?

[An example where the lines are intersecting the letterforms:](http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/60/73/0d/60730d6f7105a2bfe646cd424c1832d5.jpg)

[image]

Comment: [Similar question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13129/name-for-style-of-text-logo-where-two-colours-overlap-imperfectly/13152#13152)

Comment: if you're not referring to the 3D effect, but the effect where the lines mess with the text? if so, in physics class we called that Refraction, but when applied to design i don't know if there is an "official term" for that. "displacement" would be my best guess.

Answer (score 3):

That is an anamorphic 3d (stereo vision) illustration. If you put on a pair of red/green stereo glasses you'll see the effect. The "broken line" is part of the 3D illusion.